# Best location and permissions for socket files

Tags: permissions, socket, fhs

I will have a couple of WSGI applications. They will communicate with `nginx` using sockets. For that purpose I've created the directory `/run/wsgi` in which I will place all the socket files that are needed.

My problem is that `nginx` is not able to access the socket file. I've given ownership of `/run/wsgi` to `www-data` to no avail. What would be the correct permissions for the directory?.

I chose the `/run` directory because the commonly used `/tmp` does not guarantee persistence of the files (according to the FHS). I'm open to discussion about this decision, though.

My applications will run under Ubuntu Server 3.0.0-30 with SElinux disabled. `nginx` was installed using `apt-get`.

Comment: What is OS? If Linux, nothing about SELinux? Is nginx chrooted?

Comment: Show output of `ls -Zld /run{,wsgi}` perhaps?

Comment: /run is for miscelaneous volatile runtime data, it is a tmpfs too. Isn't a bad place for your sockets, mind you, but is _guaranteed_ not to survive reboots. Fedora mounts removable media for user under /run/media/user, perhaps /run/wsgi/sockets/ could be a good place.